# How to set screen brightness on a machine where WmiSetBrightness is not supported?

Tags: windows, screen-brightness

I'm trying to find a way to set screen brightness programmatically. Some existing SO answers point to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394549.aspx). However, when I try executing Powershell code from that article, I get errors:

```
Get-CimInstance -Namespace root/WMI -ClassName WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods
```

> Get-CimInstance : Not supported At line:1 char:1
>   + Get-CimInstance -Namespace root/WMI -ClassName WmiMonitorBrightnessMe ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotImplemented: (root/WMI:WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods:String) [Get-CimInstance],
>   CimExce    ption
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x8004100c,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.GetCimInstanceCommand

There must be some other way because there are programs that can do this.

P. S. I'm experimenting/developing on a desktop, but my target PC where I will actually use this feature is a tablet, so I'll prefer if I was actually able to control the backlight brightness rather than simply making the image darker.

Comment: You'll have to reach a bit, there is usually a little joystick-style button on the monitor.  The "other programs can do this" claim is overrated, especially on a desktop machine.  Google IOCTL_VIDEO_QUERY_SUPPORTED_BRIGHTNESS to get started, ought to show some SetDeviceGammaRamp hits as well.

Comment: @HansPassant: yep, found `SetDeviceGammaRamp` - works perfectly (on the one machine where I tested it so far) and easy to understand. As for reaching... I need it for a car PC to adjust screen brightness based on time of day. Do you really want me to reach and start tapping the screen while driving? ;)

Comment: Do you really need me to tell you not to use a PC while driving?  Automatic adjustment based on ambient light picked up by the camera is a built-in feature.